# I need clarification on tagging questions with technologies

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

The question in question:

[Reset password implementation in Struts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24784366/438992)

The code sample includes JavaMail and was tagged with JavaMail.

The question, and answer, have nothing to do with JavaMail. IMO since all the code relating to JavaMail could be (I'd argue *should* be) removed, then the tag is invalid, and implies the question pertains to JavaMail, and the answerer knows something about JavaMail.

The question and answer have nothing to do with JavaMail, hence my removal of the tag.

The question: is the purpose of tech-based tags to enumerate everything in the question, related or not, or to identify the *relevant* technologies of a question? I (fairly) regularly remove tech tags that don't actually matter to the question or the answer, have I been doing this wrong?

(The title is misleading as well, but that's a separate issue.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The purpose of tags is to help people find questions that they are likely to be interested in, and to help questions be made visible to the people with the skills and interest of answering them.

Having a tag applied to a question when that question technically is related to that tag's topic in some tangential manner, but in such a way that's not relevant to answering the question and for which that tag's followers are not really in the "target audience of people that you want to try to answer the question" isn't helpful.

The question you linked is the perfect example of this. The code in the question does use the JavaMail library, but that code has nothing at all to do with the question; it could be substituted with any number of other things (or just removed entirely) without meaningfully changing the question.